# getElementById("id").text return object but should be return value from this paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project in HTML/JS. 
The problem is that when I want get a value of the paragraph using `getElementById("id").text` I got object.

```js
var data = document.getElementById("pid").text;
console.log(data);
```

```html
<p id="pid" >Hello</p>
```

Chrome:
data returns:
`<p id="pid">Hello</p>`
But I want only `Hello` value.

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Only script and option elements has `text` property, which is not an object, though. A library has monkey patched prototypes on your page?

Answer (score 5):

`text` will not return the text node. Use `textContent` property to access the text node without parsing - vice versa to `innerHTML`. And `innerText` will not return that part of the text which is hidden via CSS. So why I suggest to use `textContent`.

```js
var data = document.getElementById("pid").textContent;
console.log(data);
```

```html
<p id="pid">Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **innerText** property like this:-

```
var data = document.getElementById("pid").innerText;
```